# php post button with different outcomes

Tags: php

```
if(preg_match("/norm/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "0" || $ruavalue === "2")
{
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<input name=\"drop1\" type=hidden value='".$drop."'>";
echo "<input name=\"boss\" type=hidden value='".$_POST['tier_two']."'>";
echo "<input name=\"main\" type=hidden value='".$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']."'>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="ruasubmit" value="RUA!" />';
echo '</form>';
Echo "drop = ";
echo $drop;
echo '<p>';
echo "ruavalue = ";
echo $ruavalue;

} elseif(preg_match("/hc/i", $drop) && $ruavalue === "0" || $ruavalue === "1") {
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<input name=\"drop1\" type=hidden value='".$drop."'>";
echo "<input name=\"boss\" type=hidden value='".$_POST['tier_two']."'>";
echo "<input name=\"main\" type=hidden value='".$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']."'>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="ruasubmit" value="RUA!" />';
echo '</form>';
Echo "drop = ";
echo $drop;
echo '<p>';
echo "ruavalue = ";
echo $ruavalue;
} else {
echo "You Have RUA'ed To This Boss";
}

if (isset($_POST['ruasubmit'])) {
    if (preg_match("/norm/i", $drop)) {

        //Normal Value Is 0 - No RUA Submitted
        if ($ruavalue == 0) {
            $ruaboss = $_POST['boss'];
            $ruauser = $_POST['main'];
            $ruasql = "UPDATE `RUASEXCELL` SET `$ruaboss`=1 WHERE Username = '$ruauser'";
            $add_rua = mysql_query($ruasql);
        }
        //Nomral Value Is 1 - Normal RUA Submitted
        elseif ($ruavalue == 1) {
            echo "nothing to do";
        }

        //Normal Value Is 2 - Heroic RUA Submitted
        elseif ($ruavalue == 2) {
            $ruaboss = $_POST['boss'];
            $ruauser = $_POST['main'];
            $ruasql = "UPDATE `RUASEXCELL` SET `$ruaboss`=3 WHERE Username = '$ruauser'";
            $add_rua = mysql_query($ruasql);
        }
        //Nomral Value Is 3 - Normal & Heroic RUA Submitted
        elseif ($ruavalue == 3) {
            echo "nothing to do";

        }
    }

    elseif (preg_match("/hc/i", $drop)) {
        //Heroic Value Is 0 - No RUA Submitted
        if ($ruavalue == 0) {
            $ruaboss = $_POST['boss'];
            $ruauser = $_POST['main'];
            $ruasql = "UPDATE `RUASEXCELL` SET `$ruaboss`=2 WHERE Username = '$ruauser'";
            $add_rua = mysql_query($ruasql);
        }

        //Heroic Value Is 1 - Normal RUA Submitted
        elseif ($ruavalue == 1) {
            $ruaboss = $_POST['boss'];
            $ruauser = $_POST['main'];
            $ruasql = "UPDATE `RUASEXCELL` SET `$ruaboss`=3 WHERE Username = '$ruauser'";
            $add_rua = mysql_query($ruasql);
        }
        //Heroic Value Is 2 - Heroic RUA Submitted
        elseif ($ruavalue == 2) {
            echo "nothing to do";
                }
        //Heroic Value Is 3 - Normal & Heroic RUA Submitted
        elseif ($ruavalue == 3) {
            echo "nothing to do";
        }

    }
}
```

my current code above will not function at all im not sure exactly what i have done wrong but the idea is when the button is pressed php checks it is clicked and then executes an SQL string based on the value of $ruavalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please strongly consider using MySQLi instead of MySQL, which will
   disappear soon enough.
2. I would suggest pulling out the common check for ruasubmit into its own test, and have the four complex cases inside it. This is just to clean up the code a bit.
3. You're risking an SQL injection attack by not cleaning up the 'boss' and 'main' entries, if they're something that a user can possibly forge.
4. Of course, you've properly connected to your MySQL server, and after the code you show, perhaps you check the status in $add_rua? Can you elaborate on "doesn't function at all"?

Comment: i will be updating to pdo shortly it works only for the 1st condition to correct myself

Comment: 1. Fix indentation on `if(strpos($drop, 'norm') !== false && $ruavalue == 0)` line so it doesn't look like all the other tests are nested within it. 2. Move common $ruaboss= and $ruauser= outside of the inner tests. 3. Do cleanup, escaping, etc. on those two variables to prevent injection attacks. 4. Is $ruaboss a _field name_? That's how you're using it. 5. Is your table name all capitals? 6. Are you getting any error message from MySQL? Have you verified that it's actually running this section of code?

Comment: i have edited my code again but even using preg_match i cant seem to get it to work, i have looked in my mysql logs my apache logs and im all out of ideas

Comment: yeah $ruaboss is a feild name, im not sure how to debug this at all

Comment: I've asked you several times what the code _is_ doing, and all you say is that it doesn't work. Are you going into the form-output section each time, or only when $_POST says there is no form submitted? Have you put in some debug `echo` or `var_dump` statements to show what the various $_POST values are when it gets to the processing part? Is it getting to the point of trying to do the database update? Are your table and field names exactly correct (spelling and capitalization)? You've got to do the heavy work of debugging here.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OxrJYB is a simplified version of how it should work but preg match still isnt working

Comment: it seems to get stuck on preg_match, yeah i have used both echo and var_dump for post and etc it never reaches the DB update process all my db details are fine i will post below the values

Comment: var_dump from 1st post - `array(3) { ["drop_1"]=> string(9) "soo10norm" ["tier_two"]=> string(16) "Immerseus-10-SOO" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }` | drop value `$drop = $_POST['drop_1'];` | tier_two value `$tier_two = $_POST['tier_two'];` |  2nd post output - `{ ["drop1"]=> string(9) "soo10norm" ["boss"]=> string(16) "Immerseus-10-SOO" ["main"]=> string(5) "admin" ["ruasubmit"]=> string(4) "`RUA!" }`